# Why is my texture blurry on my model?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

So I'm 100% brand new to blender. I've 3D modeled in Cinema 4D for class, but nothing major. Anyhow-

I'm trying my hand at making a PSX/N64 reminiscent low-poly model just for fun, but as I've entered into the texturing phase, I've noticed my textures are kind of blurry & not as sharp as I'd prefer. Obviously with the style, I want my textures to be pixelated, but they don't look as clean as the tutorials I've been following. I've posted some pictures to hopefully help resolve my issue.

[image: Top of Head]

[image: UV Map]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Hello, what the resolution / file format of your input texture ?

Comment: as @Gorgious says, this is surely due to low resolution of the image texture, If you created it in Blender, default  size is 1024*1024, try double it to 2048*2048 or even higher and try what fits your model the best way

Comment: you've chosen the Closest option in your Image Texture so the result should stick to your picture, maybe pack your image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/e8d75938c13440439f27e04f03fb785f Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: @Gorgious My image texture is 256 x 256 & I'm painting it directly in blender. I've seen it done this way before, but I'm unsure where I deviated. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMplVXdI26M&t=0s&ab_channel=Miziziziz Here's what I'm referencing.

Comment: @Milo Thanks but you haven't packed your image so we can't see any texture. Also, 256x256 is very small, are you sure your black icon is not blurry?

Comment: @moonboots Oops, my mistake. Like I said, still new to this. I think it's packed this time: https://pasteall.org/blend/4efbeda189194de1a4cd8d8da6550056
I restarted my texture so it looks a little different than above, but I added a similar X to the top of his head to help illustrate the issue. I think the problem is my texture is blurry, but I'm not sure if increasing the resolution would take away from the PSX vibe I'm going for?

Comment: I think the texture is blurry because of the falloff of the brush you used in blender. Look into the tool properties, there is a falloff property which is smooth by default, change it to "Constant"

Comment: it works fine except in Solid mode where the pixels are blurred, there must be a setting somewhere. Difference between Solid and Material Preview: https://zupimages.net/up/21/43/ropf.jpg

Comment: I can't find any solution, there may be one but if it's not the case then you can't trust the Solid view mode, you need to switch to Material preview or Rendered preview mode to see your texture as it is supposed to be. Make sure that the Image Texture is set to Closest of course.

Comment: I second the fall-off, changing to Constant will help here

Answer (score 1):

Since Blender 2.80, setting your texture's interpolation from `Linear` to `Closest` is the way to go:

[image: 2.80 Closest interp]

Prior to 2.80, switching to `Closest` instead of `Linear` in the *Image Texture* node has no effect in solid view, a pixel will automatically be blurry.
What you can do is switch to *Material Preview* to work on your texture, in that case the *Closest* option will be taken into account. It will also be taken into account in the *Rendered* preview mode and when you'll render.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but to me the cause was simply that I had **depth of field** activated on my camera which I forgot to turn off, and it made it look as if it was a texture problem because only that 1 object was visible in my viewport in that moment!